# How to transfer SSL from Windows to Linux server in shared hosting?

Tags: linux, ssl, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I've found some tutorials about transferring SSL from Windows to Linux server such as this one here: https://major.io/2007/03/23/exporting-ssl-certificates-from-windows-to-linux/. But is it possible to do something like this in shared hosting because in shared hosting Apache configuration may not be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible to transfer an SSL certificate from a Windows (IIS) environment to a Linux (Apache) environment. Within a shared hosting environment, (at least the majority of them) it will not be possible to install the SSL certificate to the hosting account without the help of your hosting provider. The SSL installation requires an IP be allocated to your domain within the server's configuration, unless deployed with SNI, and a VirtualHost entry routing requested to port 443 (TLS/SSL) for your domain on that IP will have to be created. Needless to say these configurations affect the server as a whole and are chargeable services so most providers will not provide you direct access to do this. If your provider uses `Plesk` or `cPanel` or `Vdeck` then this is the case.

That being said it is well worth the money to have your hosting provider complete this configuration for you and the related services are generally pretty cheap. Most providers will average around $20.00 per year for all the services required to have your SSL function on their servers.

I would request information from your provider regarding the installation to see if it is the right solution for you.

As a note Windows (IIS) SSL certificates are commonly PKCS#12/PFX Formated. The PKCS#12 or PFX format is a binary format for storing the server certificate, any intermediate certificates, and the private key in one encryptable file. PFX files usually have extensions such as .pfx and .p12. PFX files are typically used on Windows machines to import and export certificates and private keys. Linux (Apache) will use PEM formatted certificates.The PEM format is the most common format that Certificate Authorities issue certificates in. PEM certificates usually have extentions such as .pem, .crt, .cer, and .key. They are Base64 encoded ASCII files and contain "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" statements. Server certificates, intermediate certificates, and private keys can all be put into the PEM format.

Apache and other similar servers use PEM format certificates. Several PEM certificates, and even the private key, can be included in one file, one below the other, but most platforms, such as Apache, expect the certificates and private key to be in separate files.

I would not bother with the conversion prior to contacting your hosting provider as they can obtain the PKCS#12/PFX certificate from you and then covert it when installing it on the server. You should only have to provide the PKCS#12/PFX formatted certificate.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I do this from cPanel? I have downloaded certificates from the first server. They are in .crt format but in the second server, I have cPanel access and it's asking me to enter Private key. Where can I get the private key from?

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of transferring the certificates its easy to reissue the SSL after you have migrated to another hosting platform.

Answer (score 0):

In Shared hosting, you won't have access to the webserver (IIS and Apache) to export and import SSL Certificates. For that, you will have to contact your hosting service provider to transfer the SSL Certificate.

Recently, I've moved SSL Certificate from my Windows VPS to Linux VPS with the help of the following article.

https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/move-certificate-iis-apache/

I am sure that the above link will be helpful if you want to move the SSL Certificate from Windows VPS to Linux VPS.